for zgrep how do I limit per pattern and not the entire match?
I have a file that has about 1000 patterns to match. For each pattern I want to limit for each pattern however when I use the -m option it will find the first 10 and stop. Is there a way to do this in an equivalent or speedier way?
zgrep -o -m10 -f /projects/test.indx /projects/incoming/SRR80527_2.gz;

What do those patterns look like? Are they fixed strings?

Don't just use the word pattern when asking for help with pattern matching. That's like going to a car showroom and only telling the salesman you want a "vehicle" instead of car, truck, motorbike, whatever. You need to say if you want to do regexp or string, full or partial, etc. pattern matching or you're likely to get a solution that;s less efficient and/or less robust than it could be. See how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern.

@oguzismail good question, yes they are, in restrospect may be should had added an -F option.

Had we known they were literal strings instead of regexps you'd have got quite different answers.

Here is a simple Awk script to collect all the search phrases into an array, and limit how many matches for each array element you print.
zcat /projects/incoming/SRR80527_2.gz |
awk -v limit=3 'NR==FNR { w[++n] = $0; h[n] = 0; next }
    { p=1
      for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
        if((h[i] < limit) && ($0 ~ w[i])) {
            h[i]++; if (p) print; p=0
        }
   }
}' /projects/test.indx -

Demo (with a lower limit, just to make it easier to grasp): https://ideone.com/TcxPYT
In very brief, the array w contains the search phrases, and the parallel array h contains the number of hits we have printed for each. In other words, h[42] indicates how many hits we have printed for w[42].
The NR==FNR and other basic Awk idioms should be familiar; if not, spending an hour on learning basic Awk will be time well spent.  The variable p keeps track of whether the current line should be printed, so that we only print once, even if the line matches multiple patterns in w.
In case it isn't obvious, this looks for partial matches anywhere in a line. In other words, if your search phrases include "sick" then it will find matches in "sickle" or "sickly" or "physicking".
Another thing to note is that it will print a line if it matches at least one pattern for which the limit has not been reached yet. If a line matches multiple patterns, it will increase the count for each of them.

I can't follow the GNU grep source but I can't help but feel that it ought to be constructing a single automaton out of all the patterns passed in - so matching against all in parallel.  Getting awk to test them serially seems unlikely to gain anything even if one aborts early.

I think your code may give incorrect output if two patterns overlap. More obvious if you use match instead of ~ and output substr (cf. grep -o). eg. match abcdef against a and ab

@jhnc Thanks for your comments. The second concern is certainly valid, though it depends on the OP's requirements whether it is actually incorrect. I don't see how to create a single automaton and maintain the requirements to count the number of hits per pattern.

also behaviour of: echo abcde | grep -o -e a -e ab -e bc -e cd is not entirely intuitive if patterns are searched serially, but makes more sense if searched in parallel

Updated answer given the OPs recent comment that their "patterns" are actually literal strings (untested):
zgrep -F -o -f /projects/test.indx /projects/incoming/SRR80527_2.gz |
awk 'cnt[$0]++ < 10'

or this might be more efficient if you get many more than 10 matches for every string:
zgrep -o -f /projects/test.indx /projects/incoming/SRR80527_2.gz |
awk -v m=10 '
    NR == FNR {
        cnt[$0]
        ++numStrs
        next
    }
    $0 in cnt {
        print
        if ( ++cnt[$0] == m ) {
            delete cnt[$0]
            if ( --numStrs == 0 ) {
                exit
            }
        }
    }
' /projects/test.indx -


Original answer when the question appeared to be about regexps:
zgrep for all of the regexps but then pipe the output to awk to count the matches for each of them and exit when awk has counted 10 for each regexp which will send a SIGPIPE back to zgrep to stop it running too, e.g. untested:
zgrep -o -f /projects/test.indx /projects/incoming/SRR80527_2.gz |
awk -v m=10 '
    NR == FNR {
        gsub(/\\/,"\\\\")  # double the backslashes for dynamic regexp use
        cnt["^(" $0 ")$"]  # add anchors so we only match the whole line
        ++numRes
        next
    }
    {
        matched = 0
        for ( re in cnt ) {
            if ( $0 ~ re ) {
                matched = 1
                if ( ++cnt[re] == m ) {
                    delete cnt[re]
                    if ( --numRes == 0 ) {
                        exit
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    matched  # only print the input line if it matched any re remaining in cnt[]
' /projects/test.indx -

We zgrep first for efficiency so we don't need to execute the relatively very slow awk loop for every line of the gzipped file, just for the lines that contain a match, and so awk gets the exact matching strings that zgrep found so we can avoid best we can any issues related to our awk script and zgrep doing multi-regexp matching differently.
We need to double any backslashes in the res for awk since awk will be using them in a dynamic regexp (which gets parsed twice) context at $0 ~ re while zgrep will be using them in a literal regexp (which only gets parsed once) context, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps.
Since zgrep -o will output the full string that matches each regexp, we need to add start/end of string anchors to the regexp we'll be using in awk so the regexp matches the whole input line and thereby best avoids partial matches, e.g. if one regexp was a substring of another.
If you have any specific issues with multiple regexps matching on 1 line or anything else related to the awk loop being different from the way zgrep handles multiple regexps then you'd need to describe those issues, state how they should be handled, and provide sample input/output showing them in your question.
It occurs to me it might actually be useful for you to see which lines matched which regexps, if so you could tweak the above to:
zgrep -o -f /projects/test.indx /projects/incoming/SRR80527_2.gz |
awk -v m=10 '
    NR == FNR {
        gsub(/\\/,"\\\\")  # double the backslashes for dynamic regexp use
        cnt["^(" $0 ")$"]  # add anchors so we only match the whole line
        ++numRes
        next
    }
    {
        for ( re in cnt ) {
            if ( $0 ~ re ) {
                matches[re] = matches[re] $0 ORS
                if ( ++cnt[re] == m ) {
                    delete cnt[re]
                    if ( --numRes == 0 ) {
                        exit
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        # only print the input line if it matched any re
        for ( re in matches ) {
            print re ORS matches[re] "========"
        }
    }
' /projects/test.indx -

or do anything else you like to produce such reports.
